# How do I fix this shading?

Tags: shaders

[image]

All of my Blender models have this type of shading and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the object. Go to object property (box icon over the right-side panel of properties), go to NORMAL, check "smooth" normals. Use 15º, if that doesn't work, use 63º.
If you still get bad shading, you need to refine your faces modeling (to be more parallel instead of crossing to the nearest vertex).